# How to merge many folders in one folder in python?

Tags: python

I need to merge many folders in one folder with respecting their order which based on time, For that I have tried:

```
import os
import shutil
DestFolder =  'C:\\Users\\user\\Folder1'
SrcFolder1  = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Folder2'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk((os.path.normpath(SrcFolder1)), topdown=True):
    for name in files:
        SourceFolder = os.path.join(root,name)
        shutil.copy2(SourceFolder, DestFolder)
```

I have three folders: SrcFolder1,SrcFolder1, DestFolder

SrcFolder1 contains:

```
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=54.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=b8.npy
```

SrcFolder2 contains:

```
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=5f.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=ab.npy
```

I have executed my code with the first SrcFolder1 , then when the second SrcFolder2, the resulted DestFolder is:

```
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=5f.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=54.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=b8.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=ab.npy
```

However, I need that mys DestFolder is organised like this:

```
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=54.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=b8.npy
 Test1_Key=90_Msg=5f.npy
 Test2_Key=90_Msg=87.npy
 Test3_Key=90_Msg=ab.npy
```

Comment: As an aside, there is no need to sort the files. `shutil.copy2` also copies file stats so they will have the same timestamp as the original. The directory doesn't care what order they come as.

Comment: @tdelaney, could you please see the updated question?

Comment: Do you want to sort them based on file creation time?

Comment: unixy systems don't track file creation time and python doesn't have any builtin way to do it for windows. If you are on Windows you should also be using the win32 extensions. After copying, you can use the (win32file.SetFileTime)[http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__SetFileTime_meth.html] function. In fact, you could copy with (win32file.CopyFile)[http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__CopyFile_meth.html] call to do the copy also. I don't have a Windows system, so can't verify. But that should do it.